# CORS works for direct requests to API but not for static files (like css)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

We are developing a project which is consisted of an Android `Mobile App` along with a `Web API`. The web API is Asp.net MVC Core.

I have enabled the `CORS` service on my `Startup.cs`, hence Mobile app API calls are Cross Origin accessible and I receive `access-control-allow-origin →*` in the response headers.

A part of the result that API returns to the mobile app request is HTML (to be shown as an ad in a mobile view) containing some CSS files. When the HTML is loaded in the Mobile View, CSS files do not load because they seem not to be Cross Origin accessible.

Is there something I'm missing? Have I missed any configuration steps?

---

*my CORS configuration is as follows:*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RTBCors",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            //.AllowCredentials()
            );
    });
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal.CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("RTBCors"));
    });
    services.AddMvc(...);
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors("RTBCors");
    app.UseMvc(routes => .... );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is app.UseCors("RTBCors"); before app.UseStaticFiles(); ?

Comment: @itikhomi no, it is after that line

Comment: Change it and try, set CORS before static files app.UseCors("RTBCors"); app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseMvc(routes => .... );

Comment: I solved this problem using middleware in C#.  My code is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228891/7350549)

Answer (score 2):

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                {
                    if (context.File.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".json"))
                    {
                        var origin = context.Context.Request.Headers[CorsConstants.Origin];
                        var requestHeaders = context.Context.Request.Headers;

                        var isOptionsRequest = string.Equals(context.Context.Request.Method, CorsConstants.PreflightHttpMethod, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                        var isPreflightRequest = isOptionsRequest && requestHeaders.ContainsKey(CorsConstants.AccessControlRequestMethod);

                        var corsResult = new CorsResult
                        {
                            IsPreflightRequest = isPreflightRequest,
                            IsOriginAllowed = IsOriginAllowed(Policy, origin),
                        };

                   if (!corsResult.IsOriginAllowed)
                        { context.Context.Response.StatusCode = 204;
                           }
                    }
```

Try my complete sample https://github.com/DureSameen/CorsStaticFiles